# Where to put Vue configurations (in an Ionic project)

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, webpack

I am using Ionic + Vue.

I want to disable Vue hot-reload.

I found this: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/hot-reload.html#usage

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
      options: {
        hotReload: false // disables Hot Reload
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can't figure out where to put this.

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup suggests to put it in `webpack.config.js`, but I don't have such file in the root of my project. I tried to add this file with the suggested configuration but it didn't have an effect.

I found `vue.config.js` at the root, and tried to add the above configuration in it, but got errors about unexpected configuration keys when I tried to run (using `ionic serve`, from the command-line).

Where should I put this configuration?

UPDATE: I tried to implement Felipe's suggestion, and it worked on its own, but I also have this: `config.module.rules.delete('eslint');`.

When I use both this and Felipe's suggestion - I get "error in ./src/App.vue" on `ionic serve`, and a more elaborate error when I open the page:

[image]

My full `vue.config.js`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
        .loader('vue-loader')
        .tap(options => {
          // modify the options...
          return { ...options, hotReload: false }
        })
  }
}
```

For more info, take a look [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader) into the docs where they specifically mention how to change the vue-loader options

Comment: thank you! It works "on its own", but I still have trouble to get it to work with my existing `vue.config.js`. I updated the question to reflect this, maybe you could help? Please see additional text following the `UPDATE:` marker. Thank you!

Comment: Apparently vue-template-compiler must be installed into devDependencies same version as @vue. Can you try removing node_modules and installing again along with this package?

Comment: The `package.json` and entire build configuration was created automatically by `ionic`. I'm a little worried about breaking other stuff. e.g. I already have `"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",` there (I'm guessing by its name that it might conflict with a package called `vue-template-compiler` but I might be totally wrong)... why is it so complicated to just turn off a feature? :((

Comment: Can be a little tricky, just for questioning, why do you need to remove the eslint? It can be very needed when we want to apply good design patterns. You could instead change the rules that annoys you through changing the .eslintrc.js file

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried to disable it before but failed. But now you inspired me to try again and I succeeded. I wanted to disable `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`. Before, I tried `"no-unused-vars": "off"` and it didn't have effect. But just now I tried the full `"@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off"` and it works! Unfortunately, seems that I was wrong to think the HMR cfg thing works on its own. Now, even without the linter deletion line, I get the error I mentioned earlier (the first SS under "UPDATE")

Comment: BTW, seems that https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler is for Vue 2, but I'm using Vue 3...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226442/discussion-between-felipe-malara-and-obe).